# Typing in the input field creates a new component for each character

Tags: reactjs

I have input fields in my React app that start off empty from an albums array in my state and then I'm trying to add them to my state and update the empty array with the values typed in. My problem is that each time I type in the input field it creates a new object and a new component for every character typed.

```
this.state = {
      albums: [{title:"", date:"", description:""}],
    };

downloadChange (event) {
   const { name, value } = event.target;
   this.setState(prevState => ({
   albums: [...prevState.albums, {[name]: value}]
   }));
  }

render() {
this.state.albums.map(album => (
          <Downloaded
            key={album.id}
            album={album}
            downloadChange={this.downloadChange}
          />
        ))}
}
```

**Downloaded Component**

```
<Input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="Title" value={this.props.album.title} onChange={this.props.downloadChange}/>

<Input type="date" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date" value={this.props.album.date} required pattern="\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}" onChange={this.props.downloadChange}/>

<Input type="textarea" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Description" value={this.props.album.description} onChange={this.props.downloadChange}/>
```

Comment: I'd suggest printing out (`console.log()`) your state in your render. My guess is that you're accidentally setting it to a type you don't want, which is causing the mapping of albums to instead be mapping characters.

Comment: it works - handlers called for each input (the same) - handler creates new albums entry on every keystroke as on every keystroke onChange is called ........ write what you want to achieve

Comment: @TristanWiley it creates a new object for each character typed https://imgur.com/a/kqAF6Z5. Also `console.log`s each time a character is typed.

Comment: Just add a `commit` button for your Input Field since you actually don't need to bind `save` with `onChange` base on your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[...preveState.albums, {[name]: value}] adds one more object to the albums array. You just want to update a key for the first Array object. You can do this by.

```
downloadChange (event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        albums: [{...prevState.albums[0], [name]: value }]
    }));
}
```

Comment: hey this works but it `console.log`s state for every character typed in the render function. Is this bad practice or is it fine?

Comment: You can remove the console.log statement from your application. It is not recommended to use console.log while deploying your application for end users. You can use console.log to output values in console while development.